# How could I get value in an array or how could I convert array to string?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$tId = $this->its_model->get_status_type($property_id);
print_r($tId);
$tsId = $this->its_model->get_sub_status_type($tId);
```

The `$tId` returns this:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [tId] => 2 ) )

And now I need to use the value 2 in the second line of code. As it is in the form of array I am getting an error. How could I get the value only that is 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if

```
$tId is
Array ( [0] => Array ( [tId] => 2 ) )
```

it should be simply

```
echo ( $tId[0]['tId'] ) // should print 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Data you are trying to return but if your data is one dimensional, instead of returning

```
$query->result_array();
```

you can simply use

```
$query->row_array();
```

This returns a single row/flat array rather than a multidimensional array that you need to select the index or loop through. It will be as easy as

```
echo $tId['tId']
```

Alternatively you can return an object by using

```
 $query->row() or $query->result();
```

You can then call the value by using

```
 echo $tId->tId;
```